# What is my "Home address" as an international student (for Schengen visa)

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I am filling out a Schengen Visa (the top right says "Formular C1", if that matters). Question 19 asks me to give my "home address".

I am an international student, the place I consider to be my 'home' is in the US. However, I will be at my college dorm in the UK until I travel to Austria (the place I'm filling out the Visa for).

For question 19, should I give the address of my 'home' in the US, or my 'college dorm' in the UK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From experience, when dealing with "Home address", the author of the form usually mean your most recent "registered address".

As you are living in the UK, I assume you have registered your stay with the authorities there. This could be for tax reasons.

I would use your current address in the UK on the form.